# How do I calculate date difference in PHP and stored The Value In SQL

Tags: javascript, php, date

I am able to store these date values in DB with php and MySQL. but I want to count the date difference (days only) like if I am selecting "Date From" as 08-05-2016 and then "Date To" as 08-11-2016 ... it will calculate the days difference as "7" before submitting in leave count box the values on run time and run it in query to store it in DB.

Below is the text values codes.

```
Date From: <input type="date" name="from">
Date To: <input type="date" name="to">
Leave Count: <input type="text" name="leavecount">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: If you want to date difference calculated before the form is submitted, you'll need javascript to do that, not PHP

Comment: How i can do with javascript???

Comment: you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)

Answer (score 0):

use the following in php code of portion.

```
$date1=date_create("2016-08-05");
$date2=date_create("2016-08-11");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

now print $diff, it will list out all the records, like date, day, month, years etc between two dates.